# What is a (the?) good starting point for learning the modern "higher" mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, homotopy-theory

As many of you know, category theorists are currently doing, among other things, a great job in advertising their modern developments. And I must say, this works for me - in particular, I find myself spending more and more time in [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage) and the [n-category cafe](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/), fully understanding probably tiny bits of what they say there, and feeling that I really should get a grasp of the great picture at some point. My problem is, as for many students from the "analysis camp", almost total lack of background, except maybe some basic algebraic topology and even more basic algebraic geometry.

So the question is - where should I start in order to understand the ideas they refer to?

- Homotopy theory? This looks like a vast subject, and it's not quite clear for me what aspects of it I should learn. Simplicial methods? Model categories? The latter, for instance, seems pretty abstract and unmotivated until you do some "real" homotopy theory, which looks like a great deal to learn.
- Homological algebra? An even more basic-looking thing, so this might be a good idea to learn it first. Again, to what extent? Is the derived category formalism enough?
- Algebraic geometry - etale cohomology, in particular - at least in order to motivate...
- Topos theory? This is just scary...
- Homotopy type theory? Looks relatively self-contained at first glance, but currently not developed enough to help understanding the "real" stuff. Besides, it drags along logic and type theory as prerequisites, which is even farther away from "the meat"...

Edit: there are related questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301366/what-is-the-minimum-required-background-to-understand-articles-in-the-nlab), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65559/mathematics-needed-for-higher-dimensional-category-theory?rq=1) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74642/if-i-want-to-study-jacob-luries-books-higher-topoi-theory-derived-ag-what) (see Jacob Lurie's answer, it's really helpful).

Comment: Topos theory is not scary in the least, especially not compared to the higher abstract nonsense you are talking about. But it seems to me you are worried about sinking into generalities – so first you must answer the question, what is it you _really_ want to do?

Comment: @ZhenLin: Since I don't have immediate applications in mind - my answer would be: finally switch from vague handwaving and the "wow this must be cool" impression to actually understanding something and incorporating the basics of their intuition into my own mathematical worldview. And maybe use their insights to understand the relevant bits of mathematical physics. Which is in turn related in some ways to my own research interests. In any case, I don't think that vain curiousity needs to be justified. :)

Comment: Topos theory is a lamb, and has the benefit of being a field that's pretty well established as category theory goes. You can get a good foothold by just thinking of them as funny set theories. Some of the other stuff you mention haunts me in my sleep...

Comment: We do not choose our inclinations. We're born with them. Your whole endeavour goes against your very nature. (I'd know, since unfortunately I share similar frustrations). By the way, most people who like what you describe are usually weary of our field and of what we like, and the reverse is also generally true. You just have to accept the fact that some urges and curiosities are doomed to [never be satisfied](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM_p1Az05Jo&t=64), and learn to move on.

Comment: @Lucian: "We do not choose our inclinations. We're born with them." - I totally agree with this. But don't make snap judgements: I actually do feel much more inclined towards the abstract nonsense way of thinking than it is usual among analysts. And that's precisely the reason why I want to learn this. I also don't like the whole idea of dividing mathematics into camps that barely understand each other.

Comment: Also: it's not really mentioned in your question, but what kind of grounding in straight up category theory do you have?

Comment: Mathematics is indeed undivided, as it is part of truth, and truth is usually self-consistent. Plants also form an undivided self-consistent whole. Yet, many people enjoy fruits, while only few like vegetables, and almost no one consumes grass or flowers. I believe you when you say that your fondness for this field exceeds that of your peers; but judging by your own post, it seems that it's not by much. Furthermore, understanding is born of pursuit, and lack of attraction is the enemy of pursuit. What you think of as not-being-meat is, for those of a different bent, the tastiest of flesh.

Comment: ...and what you perceive of as a mere means to an (analytical) end is, for these others, the very core and purpose of math and existence.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: Read parts of MacLane's "Categories for the working mathematician" on an on-demand basis. So very little, I guess.

Comment: @Lucian: Of course. That's why in my "general-purpose" part of mathematical education I'd like to aim for broad topics that connect, and have impact on, different areas of mathematics, therefore being of more or less universal interest. Besides, if I'm not interested in something, this is usually because I don't know what exactly is there to be interested in.

Comment: @Lucian: BTW, algebraic geometry is another broad topic which I would like to learn at least to some extent. Which brings us again to the same problem: it's impossible to learn everything, so we have to choose carefully. Which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Lucian: Not helpful.

AlexanderShamov: Gotcha. I can say you can get a start on topos theory without having to nearly master Mac Lane. And topos theory does play a big part in the branches of abstract nonsense that get at foundational issues, if that's an interest of yours. If topology is more your thing, that stuff's beyond my ken...

Comment: @MaliceVidrine: Thanks. Actually, I called toposes scary just because the point of view that they are "funny set theories" (and also "funny spaces" somehow) is the only thing I know about them. :)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74642/if-i-want-to-study-jacob-luries-books-higher-topoi-theory-derived-ag-what

Comment: I vote to close. The question (as well as its potential answers) is entirely subjective. My advise is: Just go ahead, learn what you want to learn. But after some years try to find some thread and do your thesis.

Answer (score 2):

So much of my advertisement of topos theory has been done in the comments. I compare topoi to "funny set theories" because they come with their own internal (and structural) form of separation and "power objects", as well as many structures naturally like other common set-theoretic constructions. I actually came to set theory via elementary topos theory, and I found it a pretty natural way to think about set theory. So if "set theory" doesn't make "topoi" sound less daunting, maybe it will work the other way around!

The connections to logic are well known, but it's also the case that many interesting categories can be viewed as presheaf topoi (not the least of which is the category of simplicial sets).

It's not hard to find books explicitly about topoi, but I thought I would mention Steve Awodey's "Category Theory"; it's a readable introduction to category theory generally, but it spends a lot of time on the structure of presheaf categories (which are always topoi), and many of the exercises have a strong topos-theoretic leaning.

Answer (score 0):

nLab is an encyclopedia.  Not all of it would be understandable to everybody.

I would vote for algebraic geometry for having a nice mix of regular maths and category theory.  You can couple this with topos theory, since Grothendieck sheaves are an important aspect of it.  MacLane and Moerdijk's book is probably the most accessible book for topos theory.